# Redirect subscribers if they are in Woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, user-roles

There is a lot of plugins available that makes this possible, but they are not for free, so I'm actually trying to restrict shop, checkout and cart page, just for people registered as customers, I test this code below on `functions.php` file:

```
global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo(); 
if (user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" ) && isset($_GET['page_id']) && $_GET['page_id'] > 0 && get_option( 'permalink_structure' )=="" && $_GET['page_id'] == woocommerce_get_page_id('shop') ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/customer-register' ) );
    die();
}
```

But it's not working, maybe is more complex than I thought, do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following custom hooked function:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'subscribers_redirection' );
function subscribers_redirection() {
    if ( ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) 
    && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() ) ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/customer-register' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

It should work.

> You don't need to restrict cart and checkout pages as if there is no products added to cart, nothing is displayed.

Comment: thank you!, you solve my issue, it is working now!...but I would like to know what I was doing wrong, to learn. Can you explain?

Comment: @KennyAmaro For redirections in WordPress/Woocommerce/php, your code need to be hooked to work, like in this very specific hook, that will make the correct trigger.

Comment: this is the hook isn't? add_action( 'template_redirect', 'subscribers_redirection' ); ?

Comment: @KennyAmaro The hook is [**`template_redirect`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) *(a Wordpress action hook).*

Comment: I have a problem while working with this solution @LoicTheAztec